# Heap Corruption Detected in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I keep getting the error Heap Corruption Detected. I have read through several questions on here, but I can't quite find out what is causing this in my code. I am trying to create a 2d array that will hold a matrix that is read from a text file.

```
// Create a 2d matrix to hold the matrix (i = rows, j = columns)
matrix = new int*[cols];

for(int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[rows];
}

// Populate the matrix from the text file
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        inputFile >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

My destructor is:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    delete[] matrix[i];
}

delete[] matrix;
```

I've tried debugging, but that does do much help in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should barely ever have to manage memory yourself in C++. `new` and `delete` should be replace with RAII.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
matrix = new int*[cols];

for(int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[rows];
}
```

For an array with `cols` elements, the index is from `0` to `cols - 1` inclusively.

The heap corruption will be detected when

```
delete [] matrix;
```

Since `matrix[cols]` write a position out of array bound.

---

UPDATE

As @DanielKO (thank you buddy :p) pointed out in the comment

> there is a mismatch, the "Populate the matrix..." loop makes "i"
>   iterate over "rows" when it should be iterating over "cols".

Comment: Also there is a mismatch, the "Populate the matrix..." loop makes "i" iterate over "rows" when it should be iterating over "cols".

Comment: Thank you both! I knew it was something weird like that. I just couldn't quite spot it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        inputFile >> matrix[i][j];
```

When you allocated you went from 0 to cols in i.  Now you're changing i to be rows.

**EDIT:** Below would honor your commented row/column rules and follow RAII:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(rows, std::vector<int>(cols));

for( int i=0; i<rows; ++i ) {
   for( int j=0; j<cols; ++j ) {
      inputFile >> matrix[i][j];
   }
}

// no need for delete matrix cleaned up when leaving scope.
```